# Move centred div over to right with jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have a div that is centred on the page with margin:auto.

```
<div id="click"></div>
```

When it is clicked on, I would like it slide over 100px to the left. This is the jquery I have tried but it doesn't seem to work:

```
$("#click").click(function(){
$(this).animate({"left":"+=100px"}, "slow");
```

});

This is [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XqqtN/4651/).

Can anyone explain to me where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Change Like This:** 
**CSS:**

```
#click {
position:relative;
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
background: yellow;
margin:auto;
}
```

**Script:**

```
$("#click").click(function(){
$(this).animate({"left":"+100px"}, "slow");
});
```

You should add a attribute of `position: relative` on `the div` and change the `+=100px` to `+100px`.
The reason is: a Element must have a `position:relative` or `position:absolute` to flow some position on a page. 
 For more information: [click this.](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#normal-flow)
**This is [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XqqtN/4656/)**

Comment: Is there something wrong on my answer? I seem to resolve the question.